# PHP: bin2hex and working with impossible numbers

Tags: php

Haven't slept in awhile, so I'm probably missing something simple. Basically, I am taking a number and converting it to three characters. Max number of possibilities is 256*256*256 (16777216). I convert it with:

```
public function s_encode($num) {
  $num = chr($num / 65536).chr($num / 256).chr($num % 256);      
  return bin2hex($num);  
}
```

And convert it back with:

```
public function s_decode($hex) {    
  $a = pack("H*", $hex);
  $b = ord(substr($a, 1, 1));
  $c = ord(substr($a, 2, 1));
  $d = ord(substr($a, 0, 1));   
  return (($d * 65536) + ($b * 256)) + $c;
}
```

What's strange, is this actually works. It does what I want it to, but how could it? In the first code, where I convert it to three characters, the second part of the conversion is:

`chr($num / 256)`

If the number is greater than 65536, this should cause an error, but it doesn't. If I were to use unpack instead of bin2hex, it will cause an error. bin2hex won't. Why and how is bin2hex so magical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chr()` only looks at the lowest 8 bits of its input:

```
echo "'".chr(320)."'";
```

yields...

```
'@'
```

as does...

```
echo "'".chr(64)."'";
```

http://ideone.com/65Itz

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php), `chr` will take the parameter modulo 256. Even negative integers work. `bin2hex` doesn't do that operation, and fails on invalid inputs.